# gbm could make prediction out of thin air?

Tags: r, boosting, missing-data

The R implementation of gradient boosting machine could deal with missing data, a well known and very useful feature (`gbm` package). However, when a trained model is asked to make prediction on a test set with missing values, it has some unintuitive, rather surprising result.

I made a data frame with one row of NAs, that is, all the predictors are absent, and this became my test set. And I call `predict` and still got a non-NA predicted value. How could this happen?

Furthermore, this predicted value is very close to, but not exactly the mean of the response, as seen the code below. What is this value?

```
set.seed(12345)
X = matrix(rnorm(5*100), ncol=5)
colnames(X) = paste("X", 1:5, sep="")
y = rnorm(100)
df = data.frame(y=y, X)
test.df = data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=ncol(X)))

bm <- gbm(y~., data=df, distribution="gaussian", n.trees=100, cv.folds=10)  
best.iter <- gbm.perf(bm,method="cv", plot.it=FALSE)
pred = predict(bm, newdata=test.df, n.trees=best.iter, type="response")
pred
[1] 0.06221279
mean(y)
[1] 0.06415998
```

EDIT : Not that I think they matter, but here are the version of gbm and R i'm using

gbm 2.1.1

R 3.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the default argument, `bag.fraction=0.5`. At this setting, for each tree a random 50% of the data is used for fitting. In your code, `pred` is the mean response for the 50% of rows that were chosen for the 100th tree. If you set `bag.fraction=1` the mean prediction equals the mean response:

```
bm <- gbm(y~., data=df, distribution="gaussian", n.trees=100, cv.folds=10, bag.fraction=1)
```

Comment: Thks for pointing this out. Back to my original Q. So when no data is present, it just spits out the mean of the data used for training the last tree. This is not exactly widely known and stated in the help doc.